# $scope or scope in $scope.$watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Found such an idea in [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html):

> Notice how the value function takes the scope as parameter (without
>   the $ in the name). Via this parameter the value function can access
>   the $scope and its variables.

```
$scope.$watch( function( scope ) {
  return scope.val;
...
```

instead of what i used to:

```
$scope.$watch( function() {
  return $scope.val;
...
```

Is it really better? And what is the reasoning behind this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [AngularJs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

> function(scope): called with current scope as a parameter.

So it does not change the behavior of your code. However this version prevents a capture of the $scope variable inside the callback :

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope) {
    return scope.val;
}, function(value){ });
```

Comment: can you explain please that "prevents a capture of the $scope variable inside the callback"? Or give an example! Thanks a  lot!